# LibGit2Sharp errors when initializing Repository

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015, libgit2sharp

I installed LibGit2Sharp via NuGet into a VS add-on I'm (re-)writing (Visual Studio 2015). The code compiles fine, but it barfs when I try to allocate the Repository:

```
using (var repo = new Repository(@"C:\Path\MyProject"))
```

The thing is, it *used to work*. I was testing it out, and the code ran fine. Then--*bam*--I ran it again and it stopped working. The specific error:

```
{"Unable to load DLL 'git2-785d8c4': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}
```

From what I understand about NuGet--which isn't a lot--it's supposed to set all that up so I don't have to worry about it. So I uninstalled it and re-installed it.

The weird thing about LibGit2Sharp is the *old* version shows up first (v0.22.0) and "version 1" shows up second (v1.0.160). I installed 0.22.0 the first time, so I tried the second one (v1.0.160) the next time. But v1.0.160 didn't work at all (none of the code compiled, errors galore). So I uninstalled v1.0.160 and installed v0.22.0 again. Now it all compiles again, but I get the error above.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

For others who might come into this thread in the future:

Put 'git2-785d8c4.dll' in the same directory where your output exe is, then it will work.

you can find it in ..\LibGit2Sharp\bin\Debug(Release)\lib\win32\x86

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the .NET framework version your project targets has changed? Are you able to target .NET framework version 4.5 (rather than 4.51 or any other higher version, such as 4.6) and try again?

Comment: I kept trying and it eventually started working again. Not sure what changed, but the .NET framework version wasn't the problem. Thanks for the reply, though!